# Error 401 while trying to connect to URL for reading xml

Tags: java, servlets, https, connection, inputstream

I'm trying to read an xml file via connecting to url and read the input stream, but i have an error 
"java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://...."

i handled the case of authentication via Authenticator class

here is the code :

```
    private static InputStream getConnection(String url) {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {

            final String login="cloudtest@arrow.com";
            final String password="password";

            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {          
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(login, password.toCharArray());

                }
            });

             URL myUrl = new URL(url);


             URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
             urlConn.connect();
             in = urlConn.getInputStream();




        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return in;
    }
```

Comment: How the `Authenticator` is used to pass the credentials to server ? Not sure if you have checked the type of authentication the server supports (Basic/Form etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try below code [Source](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java_Servlets/code36.html)

```
 private static InputStream getConnection(String url) {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {

        final String login="cloudtest@arrow.com";
        final String password="password";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {          
                return new PasswordAuthentication(login, password.toCharArray());

            }
        });

         URL myUrl = new URL(url);


         URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();

         urlConn .setDoInput( true );

        // stuff the Authorization request header
        byte[] encodedPassword = ( login + ":" + password ).getBytes();
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        urlConn .setRequestProperty( "Authorization",
                        "Basic " + encoder.encode( encodedPassword ) );


         urlConn.connect();
         in = urlConn.getInputStream();




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: the same problem, error 401,
i need to ask a question.
can the host control how can i connect the URL and authenticate ??

Comment: Yes its controlled on server ... my code assumes your Server is using basic Authentication. so while setting requestProperty I am setting `Basic ` and then encoded username and password

Comment: Thanks rahul, i appreciate your response, I'll communicate with them

Comment: I am having the same issue. Somehow the code was working correctly before but even while not being changed in a long time, it just stopped working and is failing with "too many redirections" message which is actually a multiple call to the same authenticator which does not seem to be able to access the resource and therefore is defaulted again to authenticate. :(